# vector's emplace_back - vector as a constructor argument

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following structs:

```
struct A{};

struct B
{
    B(std::shared_ptr<A> a, int x): a_(a), x_(x){}

    std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
    int x_;
};

struct C
{
    C(std::vector<B> v, bool c){}
};
```

I would like to insert an object of type C to the vector but the following code doesn't work:

```
std::vector<C> vecC;
vecC.emplace_back({std::make_shared<A>(), 2}, false);
```

Alternatively this way doesn't make sense with `emplace_back`:

```
vecC.emplace_back(B{std::make_shared<A>(), 2}, false);
```

How should I insert an object of type C to the vector ?

Comment: Why you think `Alternatively this way doesn't make sense with emplace_back:`? Problem with first version is that `emplace_back` template doesn't imply what is the type of argument so compiler is unable to figure out that `B` is expected. That is why you have to specify this explicitly.

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: "doesn't work" means that the first `emplace_back` will not compile. As @Ruks noticed the second `emplace_back` expression has an error. I wonder if the second emplace_back make sense because I'm not sure if it has better performance than`push_back` in that case.

Comment: `{...}` is a braced list, it is not an expression and it does not have a type. As a result, you can't forward it to an element constructor (this is what `emplace_back` is supposed to do).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot another pair of braces for the `std::vector`. Also, you need to tell `emplace_back()` what kind of arguments you pass it, so you need to invoke `std::vector`'s constructor:

```cpp
vecC.emplace_back(std::vector{ B{ std::make_shared<A>(), 2 } }, false);
```

Alternatively, don't use `emplace_back()` and use `push_back()` instead:

```cpp
vecC.push_back({{{std::make_shared<A>(), 2}}, false});
```

Comment: Does the `emplace_back` has better performance than `push_back` in that case ?

Comment: @Irbis It depends on implementation details of `C`.

Comment: @Irbis: There are 2 overloads for `push_back`, one taking by rvalue reference, so `C` would be moved with `push_back` whereas `emplace_back` would have to move the `std::vector<B>`